# Conflict Ctrl-I with TAB in normal mode

Tags: linux, vim, vimrc

I recently noticed that in normal mode when I type **Ctrl-i** (command for *jumps*) it is "confused" for the **TAB** key.  In particular, I have this mapping:

```
nnoremap <Tab> :tabnext<Enter>
```

Comment: `Ctrl+i` and `Tab` are identical.  Just like `Ctrl+[` and `Esc`.  If you compare what ASCII codes are sent for `Tab` and `Ctrl+i` (by typing into `od` for example), you will see that both produces ASCII 9 (011 in octal), which corresponds to "horizontal tab".

Comment: If you're running `vim` in the terminal, there's nothing `vim` could do about it: `Ctrl-I`, `Tab`, `Ctrl-Tab`, etc are the same. But you could change your terminal emulator to send a different sequence for `Ctrl-I`, eg. `\E[Y`, and then remap that key in `vim`. Example with `xterm`: `xterm -xrm '*VT100*translations: #override\n\Ctrl<Key>i:string("\033[Y")'`

Comment: For an Xterm solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/631241

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Terminal I/O applications just see the composed characters sent by the terminal**, and **cannot  distinguish amongst specific key chords**, while GUI applications can, because GUIs tend to operate in terms of key press and release messages.

Most terminals, and most terminal emulators, send a ␉ (U+0009) character down the (virtual) wire to the host system when either <kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd> or <kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> are pressed.  This is not `vim`.  This is how terminals work, and how the emulators that emulate them work too.

Similarly, and oft forgotten nowadays I observe, these terminals and terminal emulators send a ␛ (U+001B) character down the (virtual) wire to the host system when either <kbd>⎋ Esc</kbd> or <kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> are pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/Ym6D-kWIsyo

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim release.