# Mapping otherwise conflicting or unmappable keys in terminal Vim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, xterm, rxvt, kitty

Resources in the network ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1646910), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21738515), [3](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/21918)) claim that some key
combinations, among which <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-letter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-number</kbd>,
<kbd>Ctrl-i</kbd>/<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-m</kbd>/<kbd>Enter</kbd>,
<kbd>Esc</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl-[</kbd>, cannot be mapped reliably in Vim because the
terminal does not distinguish them from their unmodified counterparts (more
background in [this Gilles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/629622) and [this ASCII table article](https://bestasciitable.com/)). As
a concrete example, the maps

```
nnoremap <Tab>   :!echo A<CR>
noremap  <C-S-X> :!echo B<CR>
noremap  <C-1>   :!echo C<CR>
noremap  <C-F1>  :!echo D<CR>
```

cause both <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-i</kbd> to print A (also in Gvim) and
both <kbd>Ctrl-x</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-x</kbd> to print B.
<kbd>Ctrl-{1,2,...}</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-{F1,F2,...}</kbd> cannot be mapped,
the former not even in Gvim.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2179779) to "How to map Ctrl-a and Ctrl-Shift-a differently?" shortly
describes a solution for Xterm, but it lacks several tricky details that
may escape some. This is an attempt to provide a more complete answer.

Although this is a Vim centered question, other terminal applications with
customizable mappings can also benefit from it. Vifm is an obvious case.

Comment: I used to remapping `<Tab>`, now I afraid of it.

Comment: @Niing I suppose you didn't notice you relinquished Ctrl-i when doing that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll start with **Xterm** because it is the most complicated one. **Kitty** and **Urxvt** are tackled at the end.

#### X-resources

The [`~/.Xresources`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources) file configures Xterm (and some
other Xlib applications). Whenever you are done editing it, issue
`xrdb ~/.Xresources` and open a new Xterm to test the changes.
Start with

```
XTerm*metaSendsEscape: true
XTerm*eightBitInput:   false
```

<sup>See `man xterm` or [configuring Xterm](https://unix4lyfe.org/xterm/) for further options, such as
colors and fonts — the defaults are admittedly ugly.</sup>

#### Sending keycodes

We will follow [Leonerd's article](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/hacks/fixterms/) proposal, and have the terminal send
`CSI codepoint;modifier u`, where

- [*CSI*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences) stands for an Esc character followed by `[`.
- *codepoint* is the decimal Unicode value of the character to be mapped.
  ASCII characters have the same decimal representation in Unicode.
- *modifier* is chosen from the table below:

  | None | Shift | Alt | Alt+Shift | Ctrl | Ctrl+Shift | Ctrl+Alt | Ctrl+Alt+Shift |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |

#### Ctrl-Shift-x

Look up `X` in an [ASCII table](https://bestasciitable.com/) and find that its decimal value is 88.
Therefore `CSI 88;5 u` should be sent to Vim. This goes in `.Xresources`:

```
XTerm*Translations: #override\
    Ctrl ~Meta  Shift <Key>x   :string("\033[88;5u")
```

<kbd>Ctrl-Shift-x</kbd> now produces the sequence in quotes. A tilde
negates the modifier, i.e., `~Meta` means that Alt is not pressed (Meta
means Alt). `033` is Esc in octals.

There should be no spaces after the backslashes (Xrdb would warn you of
the mistake) and, as will be seen ahead, multiple bindings should be
separated from each other with `\n\`.

#### Tab and Ctrl-i

`i` is decimal 105 and `Tab` is decimal 9, but both <kbd>Ctrl-i</kbd>
and <kbd>Tab</kbd> send 9, as the [ASCII table article](https://bestasciitable.com/) explains. So
<kbd>Ctrl-i</kbd> must send a different sequence to disambiguate them,
and by the same reasoning as before, we conclude it is `CSI 105;5 u`.

```
XTerm*Translations: #override\
    Ctrl ~Meta ~Shift <Key>i   :string("\033[105;5u")
```

One could also add `~Ctrl ~Meta ~Shift <Key>Tab :string("\011")` but that would
be redundant since `Tab` already sends decimal 9 (octal 11).

Modified `Tab` is special as listed under "Modified C0 controls".

```
XTerm*Translations: #override\
   ~Ctrl ~Meta  Shift <Key>Tab :string("\033[Z")    \n\
    Ctrl ~Meta ~Shift <Key>Tab :string("\033[9;5u") \n\
    Ctrl ~Meta  Shift <Key>Tab :string("\033[1;5Z")
```

#### More special keys

Here belong <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd> and others.
In Xterm they already have unambiguous codes, which can be straightforwardly
determined by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Key</kbd> in Vim's insert
mode. For example, <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-F1</kbd> produces `<ESC>[1;5P`.

#### Vimrc

Now we just have to add the bindings to `.vimrc`:

```
" Disambiguate Tab and Ctrl-i
nnoremap <ESC>[105;5u <C-I>

nnoremap <Tab>        :!echo A<CR>
noremap  <ESC>[88;5u  :!echo B<CR>
noremap  <ESC>[49;5u  :!echo C<CR>
noremap  <ESC>[1;5P   :!echo D<CR>
```

The 5th line is very important: <kbd>Ctrl-i</kbd>, used to move back in
the jump list, is not <kbd>Tab</kbd> anymore in Xterm; instead it sends a
different sequence to Vim, thus *that sequence* should be mapped to what
Vim has under <kbd>Ctrl-i</kbd>.

#### Extra notes

- If you notice a delay when <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed in insert mode,
  adjust Vim's timeout settings, e.g. `set timeoutlen=1000 ttimeoutlen=20`
  (see [timeoutlen vs ttimeoutlen](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-the-difference-between-mapped-key-sequences-and-key-codes-timeoutl)).
- If in doubt what keysym should go in `.Xresources`, use `xev` to find it
  out. For example, pressing the left Windows/Super key outputs `Super_L`.
- In Xterm, [<kbd>Ctrl-Q</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd>](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12107/how-to-unfreeze-after-accidentally-pressing-ctrl-s-in-a-terminal) are reserved for
  flow control, a legacy feature.  To map them, first deactivate flow control
  by adding

  ```
  " Disable XOFF/XON
  silent !stty -ixon
  " Redraw screen
  silent !resize>/dev/null
  ```

  to `.vimrc`.
- To make the maps invisible to other TUI programs, you can keep Vim under
  a different Xterm classname, such as

  ```
  xterm -name vimterm -e vim file
  ```

  and use `vimterm` instead of `XTerm` in the `.Xresources` file. [How to
  open new files in a same Vim instance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588202/how-to-open-new-files-in-a-same-vim-instance-from-my-file-manager-or-from-comman) may prove helpful.

#### Other terminal emulators: Urxvt and Kitty

**Urxvt** uses a different syntax in `.Xresources`.
A interfering binding caused by ISO 14755 also has to be disabled.

```
URxvt*iso14755:    false
URxvt*keysym.C-i:  \033[105;5u
URxvt*keysym.C-X:  \033[88;5u
URxvt*keysym.C-1:  \033[49;5u
URxvt*keysym.C-F1: \033[1;5P
```

**Kitty** does not use `.Xresources`, the bindings go in
`~/.config/kitty/kitty.conf`:

```
map ctrl+shift+x send_text application \033[88;5u
map ctrl+i       send_text application \033[105;5u
map ctrl+1       send_text application \033[49;5u
map ctrl+F1      send_text application \033[1;5P
```

Comment: note that `xrdb ~/.Xresources` does a full replacement by default, so you will lose anything defined in `/etc` -- you may want to add the `-merge` option

Comment: @graywh The downside of `-merge` is that it will also preserve now-removed resources, potentially confusing some users when performing tests. Not all X sessions load the `/etc/X11/...` resources—mine does not—, so I went for no `-merge`. Thank you for the useful comment.

Comment: I forgot about `-override` -- that's probably what I've used in the past

Comment: Hey! In your first example you say that we have to map `Ctrl-Shift-x` to `CSI 88;5 u`. Shouldn't the modifier value be 6 instead of 5?

Comment: @AlexR, this bit is indeed a bit confusing, but no: 88 is uppercase X.  You could use `CSI 120;6 u` though (120 is lowercase x). But in the end it doesn't really matter.